# history.push sometimes triggers refresh sometimes not

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using React 17 and React Router Dom 5.2 I've encountered a strange phenomenon.
In a simply CRUD application, there is a component for listing up all items, one for creating, and one for editing.

A little bit simplified, the code looks like this:

parent:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/item/create" component={ItemCreatePage}></Route>
    <Route path="/item/:itemId" component={ItemEditPage}></Route>
    <Route path="/item" component={ItemList}></Route>
</Switch>
```

create:

```
import React from "react"
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
import { ItemCreateOrEditComponent } from "./item-create-and-edit"
import { CreateItemInput, useCreateItemMutation } from "/types"

export const ItemCreatePage: React.FC = () => {
    const history = useHistory()
    const [createItemMutation] = useCreateItemMutation()

    async function createItem(itemToSave: CreateItemInput) {
        await createItemMutation({ variables: { data: itemToSave } })
        history.push(`/item`)
    }

    return <ItemCreateOrEditComponent createOrEdit="create" saveFunction={createItem}></ItemCreateOrEditComponent>
}
```

edit:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { RouteComponentProps, useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
import { ItemCreateOrEditComponent } from "../../../components/form/item-create-and-edit"
import { UpdateItemInput, useItemQuery, useUpdateItemMutation } from "/types"

type Props = RouteComponentProps<{ itemId: string }>

export const ItemEditPage: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const itemId = props.match.params.itemId
    const [item, setItem] = useState<UpdateItemInput | undefined>(undefined)
    const { data } = useItemQuery({ variables: { id: itemId } })

    const history = useHistory()
    const [updateItemMutation] = useUpdateItemMutation()
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (data?.item) {
            setItem(data.item)
        }
    }, [data])

    async function updateItem(itemToSave: UpdateItemInput) {
        await updateItemMutation({ variables: { data: itemToSave, }, })
        history.push(`/item`)
    }
    
    return <ItemCreateOrEditComponent inputItem={item} createOrEdit="edit" saveFunction={updateItem}></ItemCreateOrEditComponent>
}
```

So, `create` and `edit` do basically the same things: Use `ItemCreateOrEditComponent`, trigger a DB function for saving (Apollo GraphQL in this case, but doesn't matter) and then go back to the list: `history.push("/item")`.
However, the strange thing is: After editing, the list is refreshed with the updated item. After creating, the list is not updated.

It's not a race condition, adding a few seconds of timeout before `history.push("/item")` doesn't change anything.

The only differences between creating and editing I see are

- For editing, the data gets fetched from the back-end
- For editing, there is a URL prop containing the items id

I cannot image why these two things should have any impact on whether a refresh is triggered or not.

**Edit:**
`ItemCreateOrEditComponent` provides a form, does some validation and transformation, and then finally calls `this.props.saveFunction(this.state.item)` in the exact same way both for edit and create. And till it comes to `history.push` I cannot see any difference in behavior there.

Comment: You will need to show what the `ItemCreateOrEditComponent` is and how it calls the `saveFunction`

Comment: @Gabriele Petrioli  See edit